# Taking Input to Arrays Issue

Tags: c++

I'm creating a console timetable application in which you can create a timetable, change it, and delete it. I'm on the stage of taking the input for the calculator. However, when I run the code, as soon as I finish taking the input, the window just closes. Here is the code:

```
int input()
{
    int numberOfElements;
    cout << "How many items do you want in your timetable? ";
    cin >> numberOfElements;
    char* itemArray[numberOfElements] = {};
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a session: ";
        cin >> itemArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        cout << itemArray[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is some code in the main function as well, but it's irrelevant (only to find out for what day it is). I want you to have a look at the first for loop in the code, where I take in input. When running this code (in a separate window altogether), it closes as soon as I give in the input. Even if I say that I want 3 sessions (or any number), it closes right after I input the first session. In case you were wondering, I already tried replacing

`char* itemArray[numberOfElements] = {};`

with

`char* itemArray[numberOfElements];`

Just in case it's useful to anyone, I'm using the MinGW compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: Please just use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of messing with `char` pointers and arrays like this. `char* itemArray[numberOfElements]` is not allowed in standard C++ since the size of arrays needs to be known at compile-time. It is allowed only as a compiler-specific extension. You would also need to allocate memory of sufficient size for each pointer `char*` in the array manually, but please don't do that. `cin >> itemArray[i];` does not allocate memory to store the string and using `cin >>` with a `char*` pointer is no longer allowed since C++20.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++)` did you mean to start at 0 and go to `< numberOfElements`?

Comment: `cin >> numberOfElements; char* itemArray[numberOfElements] = {};` is **not standard C++**.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack. Note that it doesn't always look like this. A quick usage note: When asking a "why doesn't my code work?" type question, you should provide a runnable example that people can copy and paste into their tools, compile, run and see (within the bounds of what you can expect from [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)) what you see. Use [mre] for inspiration when making this example. In this case all you need is a small `main` that calls `input` and exhibits the same behaviour you see in your program and a few include directives.

Comment: Sometimes making this minimal example is all you need to do to reduce the noise around a bug to make the bug obvious and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Standard C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So take for example the following statements in your program:

```
int numberOfElements;
cout << "How many items do you want in your timetable? ";
cin >> numberOfElements;
char* itemArray[numberOfElements] = {};//not standard C++
```

The statement `char* itemArray[numberOfElements] = {};` is not standard C++ because `numberOfElements` is not a **constant expression**.

**Additionally**, you're going **out of bounds** of the array because of the `<=` in the for loop instead of `<`. This leads to **undefined behavior**.

Better would be to use `std::vector<std::string>` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   
    int numberOfElements;
    std::cout << "How many items do you want in your timetable? ";
    std::cin >> numberOfElements;
    std::vector<std::string> arr(numberOfElements); //create vector of size numberOfElements
    for (std::string &element: arr)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the element: ";
        std::cin >> element;
    }
    for (const std::string& element: arr)
    {
        std::cout << element << "\n";
    }

}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6on-dCNW9).